# Are cracks between my steps and foundation a concern?

Tags: concrete, stairs

I have a concrete step with portico above it. I'm fairly certain it's attached via rebar as I see it in the basement area. I noticed some cracked mortar above the step and believe it to be getting worse (this may be me). I also noticed it has cracked on the left side where it meets the house. Is this something that poses a problem?[image]

Comment: All concrete cracks. If it is not cracked now it will. How old is the home? The best thing to do is make some marks on either side (permanent marker) then place a scale or tape measure across the cracks at the marks, take a very clear & focused picture. Wait a few months and repeat the picture process and evaluate the crack in a few months or a year.

Answer (score 1):

It's *kinda* hard to tell from just that picture since it's fairly zoomed in, but no, concrete/CMU steps, even if the cinder blocks appear to be attached, are totally fine to "crack" and pull away from the foundation wall, because they are in fact placed separately, typically after the ground level has been backfilled up against the house foundation wall. Then, they are sometimes filled with dirt, and then a concrete slab is poured in place. As the backfilled soil settles/shifts, the CMU wall under the front slab will adjust, typically *away* from the more firmly-in-place house foundation CMU wall.

I would be very surprised to see a house with that kind of foundation and front step/stoop built that way that has *not* had some cracking/settling like that, if it is >= 30 years old.

As Ed Beal mentioned in a comment, all concrete cracks eventually. I often hear it said as "there are two types of concrete: concrete that has already cracked and concrete that is about to crack".